# How to make a stored procedure in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new to stored procedures in mySQL and I have been having trouble with some of my homework that I have been assigned.
It's asking me to accept cust_code as a procedure parameter in my database, and then it will delete said customer with the cust_code.
Then it will delete all associated rows with this customer in the tables   'Invoice', 'line'.

Comment: Don't use a procedure for that. For one thing, it would be better as a trigger. For another, it'd be better still if `Invoice`, `Line` etc. had `FOREIGN KEY` constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Immeasurably better.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's a lesson on writing stored procedures. What it does is irrelevant, he's just learning the mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

To create a procedure with a integer parameter do something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `<procedure_name>`(IN `in_cust_code` INT)
   BEGIN
      DELETE 
      ...
      WHERE 1
        AND `<table_name>`.`cust_code` = in_cust_code
           ...
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why do you need `1 AND`?

Comment: `<database_name>` should be `<table_name>`

Comment: You don't need to do that, it just is handy when you want to comment out an "AND" line